# Installing flexplot for R 3.6.1

Tags: r

Iam new to R and I want to use flexplot to view my models. Iam using Rstudio from Anaconda. When I tried to install flexplot by

```
install. Packages("flexplot")
```

Iam getting this error:

```
Warning in install. Packages :
  package ‘flexplot’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions on the [github site](https://github.com/dustinfife/flexplot)? I.e. `install.packages("devtools"); devtools::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `flexplot` is not part of the CRAN Archive, you cannot direclty use `install.packages("flexplot")` to install this package.

As suggested by jared_mamrot you can install it from the github project page:

```
install.packages("devtools") # Devtools is a package which allows to do this.
devtools::install_github("dustinfife/flexplot")
```